# .NET 3.1: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I tried creating a log of the room containing the image and it reported this error

> [Error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDCPR.png)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details

This is controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]RoomCreateRequest request)
    {
        var roomId = await _manageRoomService.Create(request);

        if (roomId == null)
            return BadRequest();

        var room = await _manageRoomService.GetById(roomId, request.LanguageId);

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = roomId }, room);
    }
```

And this is service

```
public async Task<string> Create(RoomCreateRequest request)
    {
        var room = new Room()
        {
            Id = request.Id,
            Price = request.Price,
            NumberRoom = request.NumberRoom,
            Status = RoomStatus.Empty,
            RoomTranslations = new List<RoomTranslation>() {
                new RoomTranslation()
                {
                    Name = request.Name,
                    Description = request.Description,
                    SeoDescription = request.SeoDescription,
                    SeoTitle = request.SeoTitle,
                    SeoAlias = request.SeoAlias,
                    LanguageId = request.LanguageId
                }
            }
        };

        // Save Image
        if (request.ThumbnailImage != null)
        {
            room.RoomImages = new List<RoomImage>()
            {
                new RoomImage()
                {
                    Caption = "Thumbnail image",
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    FileSize = request.ThumbnailImage.Length,
                    ImagePath = await this.SaveFile(request.ThumbnailImage),
                    IsDefault = true,
                    SortOrder = 1
                }
            };                
        }

        _context.Rooms.Add(room);            
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return room.Id;
    }
```

Save File Image Method

```
// SaveFile Image
    private async Task<string> SaveFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        var originalFileName = 
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
        var fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}{Path.GetExtension(originalFileName)}";
        await _storageService.SaveFileAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), fileName);
        return fileName;
    }
```

This is FileStorageService code block `await mediaBinaryStream.CopyToAsync(output);` will copy name file and add to filename in "SaveFile" method, but in debug it not working.

```
public async Task SaveFileAsync(Stream mediaBinaryStream, string fileName)
{
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_userContentFolder, fileName);
        using var output = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        await mediaBinaryStream.CopyToAsync(output);
}
```

This is Class RoomCreateRequest

```
public class RoomCreateRequest
 {
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public decimal Price { set; get; }
    public string NumberRoom { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public string Description { set; get; }
    public string SeoDescription { set; get; }
    public string SeoTitle { set; get; }

    public string SeoAlias { get; set; }
    public string LanguageId { set; get; }

    public IFormFile ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
 }
```

But if I don't add the image it works.

Comment: And what is the inner exception?

Comment: Based on linked image containing error - there is some kind of mismatch with database. Have you forgot to run some migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the exception it says `Invalid Column name 'IsDefault'`. In order to fix this problem you should have column named `IsDefault` in your your `Room` table.

※I am assuming your table is named `Room` based on your context object, it may be different in your case